# The Intersection of Equivalence Relations which cover a relation

Tags: general-topology, elementary-set-theory

Exercise A.3 From John Lee( Topological Manifolds)

Let $R \subset X \times X$ be any relation on $X$, and define ~ to be the intersecction of all equivalence relations in $X \times X$ that contain $R$.

(a) Show that ~ is an equivalence relation.
(b) Show that $x$~$y$ if and only if at least one of the following statements is true: $x=y$, or $x R' y$ or there is a finite sequence of elements $z_1,z_2,\cdots,z_n \in X$ such that $x R' z_1 R' \cdots R' z_n R' y$, where $x R' y$ means  $x R y$ or  $y R x$

I proved most part of the problem but I was stuck on one direction (the third part of $\rightarrow$ ). Is there any good way to prove that if $(x,y) \not\in R'$ $\&$ $(x,y) \in $ ~ then $\exists z_1, z_2, \cdots z_n$ such that  $x R' z_1 R' \cdots R' z_n R' y$?
I don't know how to show that after finite steps, we can 'link' $x$ to $y$.

Comment: Got stuck at exactly the same part! Thank you for asking this here!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can define a relation $T$ by stating that: $$xTy\iff x=y\text{ or }xR'z_1R'\cdots R'z_nR'y\text{ for a finite sequence of elements } z_1,z_2,\dots,z_n\in X$$

Then it is not difficult to prove that $T$ is an equivalence relation with $R\subseteq T$.

That implies that $\sim\subseteq T$, and you are ready.